# Where is the change case button in Excel 2013

Tags: excel-2013

I want to change the case of a column in Excel but I can't find the button I was used to click in Excel 2010. I know I can change the case creating a temp column and then creating a formula. But I want to find that button.

So, where is the change case button in Excel 2013? Has it gone?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Actually, this option is also not available in Excel 2010 as I said above.

Comment: Try this add-in https://aneejian.github.io/Change-Case-Excel-Add-In

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "change case" functionality in either Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 out of the box.

You may have had some 3rd party product (add-in, VBA) installed in Excel 2010 and it is probably not installed with your version of Excel 2013. If you have access to your previous installation, check the add-ins and then install these add-ins for your current version.

Comment: It's sad but true. Thanks for your answer. Even in Excel 2007 there is no such a option.

Comment: Does anyone know where to find this add-in? Do I have to write this myself?